# Execute the Timer once a week

Tags: java, timer, commonj

I am using the commonJ TimerManager for sending notification emails.

Now I need to  execute the Timer once a week on Monday but I am facing some problems with the configuration.

How can I set the timer for once a week on a specific day ?

```
        TimerManager tm = (TimerManager) ic.lookup(tm_lookup);
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yy:HH:mm:SS");
        String exeDate = "23-10-2013:13:00:00";
        Date date = dateFormat.parse(exeDate);
        long oneDay = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
        long oneWeek = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 * 7;


        tm.scheduleAtFixedRate(new MyTimer(), ?, ?);
```

Thanks

Comment: the arguments are `scheduleAtFixedRate(Runnable command,
                                     long initialDelay,
                                     long period,
                                     TimeUnit unit)`

Comment: Or you could use something like Quartz-Scheduler which gives you access to Cron like execution.

Comment: something like that  tm.scheduleAtFixedRate(new MyTimer(), TimeUnit.DAYS.toDays(2), oneWeek); ??